# How to customize allure reports in Ruby with custom status

Tags: ruby, rspec, allure

Currently I'm aware allure report have status like passed, failed, broken, skip and unknown

I need to add new custom status like info to my report. How do I achieve in Ruby

Answer (score 0):

Allure doesn't provide way to add additional statuses to the report. But instead, you can use Categories feature that allows you add additional classification to each test failure.